# UK Ancestry visa

Tags: visas, uk, lhr

I have a UK ancestry visa which expires 20 Jan 2017. I would like to fly to South Africa Dec 2016 and come back 15 January 2017. Will I be allowed back in? I intend applying for a new ancestry visa before January 20th

Comment: AFAIK there is no limit on how long the ancestry visa (not ancestral, [ancestry](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/overview) ) should be valid when entering the country. You can enter on the 15th and file on the 16th and [stay](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/extend-your-visa) until the decision is made. However, my knowledge is based on the two pages linked so I am just commenting and not answering.

Comment: Please don't put your name in the subject. It should relate to your question so others can find it. I've submitted an edit for you.